# How can I install a package into a nix shell from source for debugging using flakes, equivalent to python setup.py develop

Tags: python, nix, nixos

Is there a way to include a package into a nix shell from source, ie the path linking not to a copy of the code in the nix store but to the actual source code, for debugging purposes?

I.e. I'm searching for a nix flake equivalent to running

```
python setup.py develop
```

in a conda environment instead of install.

The closest I found is using a flake.nix like

```
{
    inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
    outputs = { self, nixpkgs }:
    let
        pkgs = import nixpkgs { system = "x86_64-linux"; };
        python_library = pkgs.python3Packages.buildPythonPackage {
            pname = "python_library";
            version = "0.1";
            src = /home/user_name/python_library;
            doCheck = false;
        };
    in {
      defaultPackage.x86_64-linux = pkgs.buildEnv {
        name = "test-env";
        paths = [
          (pkgs.python3.withPackages(ps: [
            ps.numpy
            ps.scipy
            ps.matplotlib
            python_library
          ]))
          pkgs.spyder
        ];
      };
    };
}
```

Where `python_library` contains new code I wish to debug, e.g.

```
class Hello:
  def __init__(self):
    print("Hello!!! Hello!")
```

which I test via

```
>>> from python_library.test import Hello
>>> a=Hello()
Hello!!! Hello!
```

For changes in the code to take effect, I need to run

```
nix build
nix shell
```

which rebuilds the nix environment with the updated code, as long as the flake is not inside a git repository. However this rebuilding process can get quite annoying in more complex cases if there are a lot of bugs to fix and when always having to switch folder between the nix flake and the code to execute, so I was wondering if there is a way to write the flake in such a way that the nix store directly links to the source code, instead of copying it over, as is possible with anaconda?
None of the `nix develop` commands appeared to do anything like that for me.